# "not all control paths return a value" in c, Fractional discrimination

Tags: c, configuration, warnings

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isPrime(unsigned number)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 2; i < number; ++i)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0;
    scanf("%u", &a);

    bool flag = isPrime(a);
    if (flag)
    {
        printf("%u is a prime number", a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%u is not a prime number", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: prime.c, Configuration: Debug x64
> ------ 1>main.c `1>C:\Users\neuez\source\repos\test\prime.c\main.c(22): warning
> C4715:` 'isPrime': not all control paths  return a value
>
> 1>Done building project "prime.c.vcxproj".
> ======== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped =======
> ```

I think I returned the results for all control passes, but I don't know why the warnings pop up.

Comment: if the `number < 2` you are not returning anything. First of all why do you need `for` loop, it isn't making any sense?

Comment: Your loop will only ever run at most once with `i == 2`. It returns no matter what, never does `i = 3`.

Comment: `isPrime` will return an indeterminate value if `number <= 2`. Apart from that fact, your algorithm to determine if the `number` is prime is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isPrime` function does not always return a value.

```
bool isPrime(unsigned number)
{
    unsigned i;
    for (i = 2; i < number; ++i)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What would happen if the `number` argument where less than `2`? In that case, for `for` loop wouldn't run, and no `return` statement is ever executed.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a case where `number = 1 (or 2)`.

Here, you won't be entering the loop because of the set conditions.

In this case, you are reaching the end of the function without any return.